# thereby +(verb+ing) or thereby +(verb in other tenses)

Tags: grammar, phrase-requests, differences, syntactic-analysis

I've observed that "thereby" is mostly followed by **(verb+ing**) form regardless of whether the sentence takes place in past, future or present. As in this example from the dictionary:

> "The number of uninsured cars will rise and the cost to the industry
>   will increase, thereby pushing premiums up further."

.

However, I seldom see "thereby" followed by a verb in other forms such as past tense. For example:

> "This behavior increased demand and thereby pushed prices up still
>   more."

why isn't it **"pushing up the prices..."**. Is either form right,?

I'd be glad if you could give more information/examples on thereby usage

Answer (score 2):

The difference between the verb forms in these two sentences actually doesn't have anything to do with the presence of "thereby". You can see what I mean by taking "thereby" out of each sentence:

"The number of uninsured cars will rise and the cost to the industry will increase, pushing premiums up further."

"This behavior increased demand and pushed prices up still more."

In the second sentence, "and" conjoins two verb phrases with a common subject. "This behavior increased demand[. It also] pushed prices up." "Pushed" is a finite verb in an independent, declarative predicate here.

In the first sentence, "pushing" is a participle. It modifies the verb phrase "will increase".

"Thereby" is frequently used in participle constructions like your first sentence, but it doesn't have to be.

Comment: Good point, though I would argue that the participle clause headed by "pushing" modifies everything that precedes it, not only "will increase".

Comment: oh yeah--including the verb phrase headed by "will rise". good catch.

Answer (score 0):

Look at both sentences carefully please. In sentence 1, *thereby* follows the comma; however in sentence 2, there is a coordinating conjunction before *thereby*. Whenever you use *thereby* with an *-ing* form (*-ing* form is a present participle here), just place a comma before it. Whenever you use it after a coordinating conjunction (e.g. *and*), use the past or present tense.

Comment: Hello, Halil. Although the use of the future construction after _thereby_ may be less common, there are plenty of examples on the internet of 'and thereby will v ...'.